# Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric datatype to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm having following columns in a table

```
SIZE NUMERIC(14,5)    
PRICE NUMERIC(14,5)
```

when I perform this `select` query,

```
SELECT SIZE,
PRICE,
SIZE*PRICE AS TOTAL 
FROM TNAME
```

I'm getting results:

```
1.00000 90.00000    90.0000000000
1.00000 90.00000    90.0000000000
1.00000 90.00000    90.0000000000
1.00000 100.00000   100.0000000000
1.00000 30.00000    30.0000000000
```

I'm wondering why the third column is returning with 10 digits after decimal point?

Also I'm getting

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric datatype to numeric

while inserting result into another table which has the same columns with same datatype

```
INSERT INTO TNAME2(SIZE, PRICE, TOTAL)
   SELECT 
       SIZE, PRICE, SIZE * PRICE AS TOTAL 
   FROM 
       TNAME
```

Comment: _I'm wondering why the third column is returning with 10 digits after decimal point?_ then what it should be ?

Comment: A product of two factors will logically result in higher precision. If you round it, you may lose information.

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
SELECT SIZE,
PRICE,
CAST(SIZE*PRICE AS numeric(14,5))AS TOTAL 
FROM TNAME
```

Comment: There is no error while insert check the table definition of both the table TNAME2 & TName.

Comment: @Snehal: please check with my edit..the third column is not available in `TNAME` it's a calculated column whose value i want to insert in `TNAME2` table's column `TOTAL NUMERIC(15,5)`

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT  INTO TNAME2
SELECT    SIZE ,
Price ,
CAST(SIZE * PRICE AS NUMERIC(15, 5))
FROM      TNAME
```

OR

```
INSERT  INTO TNAME2 (SIZE,Price,TOTAL)
SELECT    SIZE ,
Price ,
CAST(SIZE * PRICE AS NUMERIC(15, 5)) AS TOTAL
FROM      TNAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first question, the number of decimals, there is nothing wrong. It's the basic, everyday multiplication we learn at school: Multiplying two decimal numbers produces a number with as many decimal digits as the sum of decimal digits of the operands. The number of integer digits can be up to the sum of integer digits of the operands.

Multiplying `10.11` by `12.13` produces `122.6343`. It would be VERY awkward if SQL Server broke this basic rule and arbitrarily truncated the result.

As a result, when you try to store the product in a column that accepts fewer digits, you get an overflow error. SQL Server won't change the number of digits automatically because there is no way to decide the correct action.

There are a [*lot* of ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) you can handle this, depending on the loss of precision you are willing to suffer:

- Truncate the extra digits, ie throw them away, accepting up to a unit loss. This can become a LOT of money if you store totals.
- Round to the desired number of digits. Sounds intuitive, but what about half-way values, ie 0.00005 in your case? Should it be 0.0001 or 0.0000? So we have
- Rounding up, where 0.5 becomes 1, resulting in up to .5 loss per entry
- Down, when it becomes 0, with the same loss
- Round to even or odd, where you round to the nearest odd or even number, which on average produces minimal loss. While this sounds weird, it *is* the standard defined in  IEEE 754. It's also called `banker's rounding` because it's used in bookkeeping to minimize losses due to truncation.

If you want to store fewer digits you need to decide whether you need to truncate the extra digits or how to round the number, then do it yourself in code.

In your case, you can use `CAST` to a numeric of the desired precision. This will perform rounding half up, where 0.00005 becomes 0.0001, eg:

```
INSERT INTO TNAME2(SIZE, PRICE, TOTAL)
SELECT 
   SIZE, PRICE, CAST(SIZE * PRICE as numeric(14,5)) AS TOTAL 
FROM 
   TNAME
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/648d5/9)

This will work, assuming the number of digits doesn't exceed 14, otherwise you will have to change the type of your table field.

If you want some other kind of rounding in SQL, you will have to create your own function.

Answer (score 0):

Got below useful link.
[Multiplication of numerics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/03/29/564110.aspx)
As per this link you can try as query as below

```
SELECT SIZE,
PRICE,
CAST(SIZE*PRICE AS numeric(28,5))AS TOTAL 
FROM TNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT SIZE,PRICE,CONVERT(numeric(14,5), SIZE*PRICE) AS TOTAL 
FROM TNAME
```

Write the same query in insert, it must work